# Jenkins - Copy build log from master to a shared drive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli, jenkins-scriptler

Can someone direct me here?  I have a simple job configured in Jenkins on a WINDOWS environment (master and all slaves running on windows) and  the job is supposed to run on a particular slave. When you build the job, the build log ( log.log) gets stored in ” %JENKINS_HOME%\jobs\\builds\%BUILD_NUMBER%\” on the master.

I do have a Jenkins workspace (which is required when you add a slave node) set on the slave for this job–where nothing gets stored when the job runs.

With this scenario, I would like to copy the build log (log.log file that’s available on the master) to a share drive. Please advise me the way to get this done. I have tried few plugins “Copy to slave”, “Copy Artifact Plugin” and ArtifactDeployer Plugin…I could not get them working to meet what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a second build action with the execute batch option. Put the copy command there to copy the log to another location.

Answer (score 0):

The following command kind-of works:

```
curl ${BUILD_URL}consoleFull -o ${TargetDir}/Log.txt
```

where

```
TargetDir="${WORKSPACE}/Directory/target"
```

BUILD_URL and WORKSPACE are set by Jenkins. Unfortunately Jenkins doesn't copy the whole log.  I've tried consoleText and gotten the same result: partial logs files. :-(